# SQL Server query - 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a dynamic query that will span across 2 databases.

Db1: Table1

Db2: Table2

First I will select some items based on hard coded ID's from table1 in db1.

```
Select * 
from Db1.Table1 
where Id = 123
```

`Table1` has a column called `CityId` that is part of `Db2.Table2`. So when inserting new items in `Db2.Table2`, the `CityId` is an Identity column.

Now I need something like:

```
use Db1
go

select * 
from Db1.Table1 
where Id = 123

use Db2
go

select * 
from Db2.Table2 
where CityId in (select CityID 
                 from Db1.Table1 
                 where Id = 123)   // how can I solve this cross db query?
```

Comment: 3 part name : database.schema.table

Comment: Damn, I forgot the schema....

Comment: Normal stuff, working during the weekend. I'm off for a nap!

Comment: Works perfect!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to use three-part naming:

```
select t2.*
from Db2..Table2 t2
where t2.CityId in (select t1.CityID from Db1..Table1 t1 where t1.Id = 123)
```

The default schema name is usually `dbo`, so you can be more explicit:

```
select t2.*
from Db2.dbo.Table2 t2
where t2.CityId in (select t1.CityID from Db1.dbo.Table1 t1 where t1.Id = 123)
```